# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended (in simple insert statement)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-00933

The following simple statement:

```
INSERT INTO mydb.inventory (itemID) VALUES (:itemID) WHERE playerID = :ID;
```

Generates the following error:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

I have tried it without the semi-colon as well as with, but both give me the error. I am certain that the variables are being bound as well.

All my Google searches show that this is usually caused by an ORDER BY clause, but clearly I don't have one. =P

Comment: n/m. I just realized the folly in what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

You only define a WHERE clause if you are populating the [INSERT statement](http://techonthenet.com/sql/insert.php) with a SELECT.  IE:

```
INSERT INTO mydb.inventory 
  (itemID)
SELECT :itemID FROM DUAL
```

Otherwise, you specify the values as-is:

```
INSERT INTO mydb.inventory 
  (itemID)
VALUES
  (:itemID)
```

You specify a WHERE clause when you are [updating an existing record](http://techonthenet.com/sql/update.php):

```
UPDATE mydb.inventory 
   SET itemid = :itemid
 WHERE playerid = :ID
```

Answer (score 1):

An insert can not have a where clause.  Perhaps you actually meant to `update`?

Comment: An insert can have a WHERE clause if using a SELECT to populate the values.  See my answer for details.

Comment: @OMG - Mentally then (to me) the `where` is on the sub-select.  But, yes.

Answer (score 1):

A `where` clause is rather unusual in an `insert` statement.  Perhaps you're trying to update instead?

```
UPDATE mydb.inventory SET itemID = :itemID WHERE playerID = :ID;
```

Comment: "unusual" is a somewhat understated description of something that is simply syntactically wrong.